# kendo grid row item is posted only once

Tags: c#, asp.net, kendo-grid

I am using a kendo grid control and on editing, i need to validate the data and if validated, then update some other values in the same row.

Now, i am using $.post because my datarow json is too long for $.get.

In this scenario, if i validate a row once it works fine, but the second time edit **on the same row** there is no post but i get the following error.

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter ...

If i use post on some other row, then again it works just once..

```
function onSave(e) {

   var keys = Object.keys(e.values);
    var colName = keys[0];
   .....
    var grid = $("#mapsDiv").data("kendoGrid");
    var dataItem = grid.dataSource.get(e.model.studentid);


    row = JSON.stringify(dataItem);

$.post("@Url.Action("CalculateFormattingForResult", "Maps")", {
    p_studentId: e.model.studentid, colId: colName, value: e.values[colName], p_mapHeaderId: mapHeaderId, p_yearId: yearId, classIds: classid, model: row
}, function (data) {...});
}
```

The http error says e.model.studentid is null the second time but if i check it in alert it is always there!

Similar problem mentioned [here](https://forums.asp.net/t/1746491.aspx?the%20notorious%20The%20parameters%20dictionary%20contains%20a%20null%20entry%20for%20parameter%20id%20of%20non%20nullable%20type%20System%20Int32%20)

**UPDATE**
Request first time[image]
[image]

Request second time[image]
[image]

Comment: Add a `console.log(e);` to be able to debug what's in there, it's usually better than alerts, which pause your logic and can change the scenario. Are you using MVC or webforms? Check with the Developer Tools the payload of the post, and compare it with the working one.

Comment: I don't have much idea of http requests..you can see in the updates the request are clearly uploaded

Comment: data is present in both of the requests but still there is error and it never reaches the break point in code (first line)

Comment: The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'p_studentId' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.String CalculateFormattingForResult(Int32, System.String, System.String, Int32, Int32, System.String, System.String)' in 'MapsController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters

Comment: What about those JS errors? You must solve those first of all! As you can see, the post is sent but the server has an internal error. Again, are you using MVC?

Comment: found the problem thanks to you..posting the issue

Comment: and yes i am using MVC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Andrew Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. The problem is that i use a div inside each of my kendo grid cells for styling and once i have edited my values, the dataItem that I am passing to the server gets appended with the newly edited values at the end of original json..Since these edited values contain a div element..it is blocked by http

> A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (model="...518rt14":"

I was able to see this error by going to Chrome Developer Tools > Network > click on post request url > Preview tab

Comment: I'm glad you fixed it!